# create and edit password protected excel file

Tags: excel, delphi, delphi-7

i am using delphi7 and i want to create password protected excel file in my program and also want to edit it by unprotect it using code only.
my program requirement is that i have to log data in excel file but it will not be edited by end user.So how can i do it using delphi7?

```
var
xls, xlw: Variant;
begin
{load MS Excel}
xls := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');

{open your xls-file}
xlw := xls.WorkBooks.Open(FileName := 'd:\book1.xls', Password := 'qq',
ReadOnly := True);
{save with other file name}
xlw.SaveAs(FileName := 'd:\book2.xls', Password := 'password');

{unload MS Excel}
xlw := UnAssigned;
xls := UnAssigned;
end;
```

i tried but got Program in which program only save password protected file and after creating password protected excel file i do not able to edit same file again.
So please help me.

Comment: Why did you choose to tag this question with `java` and `c#` when your question has absolutely nothing to do with those languages?

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is, I'm afraid. I tested almost exactly the same code in Delphi 2007 (I changed `d:\book1.xls` to `e:\tempfiles\book1.xlsx`, and made the similar change to the SaveAs line), and it creates `book2.xlsx` correctly and I can open it with Excel and edit it fine afterward.

Comment: In my example i am able to create password protected file by saveas statement and giving password as password parameter but after creating password protected file i am not able to edit it .like if i want to edit

Comment: In my example i am able to create password protected file by saveas statement and giving password as password parameter but after creating password protected file i am not able to edit it.                                         in my example D:\book.xls is password protected and password is qq. i want to open this file and made some changes and again save as password protected file. @ ken white

Comment: Why are you protecting the file? Aren't you meant to protect the data?

Comment: @Priyanka Mehta:  Sorry, your q + comments aren't quite clear to me. When you say "not able to edit it", a) which file are you referring to, Book1 or Book2 and b) are you attempting to edit the instance of it which your code leaves open in Excel, or by opening it using Excel's File | Open dialog and c) what do you mean exactly by "unable to edit it"?  Reason I ask is like KenW I have similar code which works perfectly and I'm having trouble understanding exactly how + where you get your problem.

Comment: Two more qs if I may:  c) what Excel version are you using?  d) Do you get the same problem if you specify ReadOnly := False, rather than True?  I'm wondering whether in your Excel version, unlike mine (2007), the ReadOnly := True "carries over" to Book2 and that's why you can't edit it.

Comment: Your comments aren't helping. I can use the code you posted (with the changes indicated in my prior comment), open Book1 with the password, change it, save it again (still as Book1), reopen it in Excel with the password, and save it from Excel, and then reopen it with my code, modify it, and save changes. You're going to need to be much more specific about the problem you're having - "I am not able to edit it" is not a sufficient problem description. Also, when adding information, please [edit] your question to do so instead of burying it in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, one more quick thing. :-) The `@` comments (which address them to a specific user) don't work if there are any spaces anywhere. IOW, a message to `@ ken white` won't arrive in my inbox, but `@kenwhite` will. That's why I didn't see your comment until now; it never came to my inbox.